# ionic3 app stuck on splash screen using build --prod flag

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am successfully building my `ionic 3` application using `--prod` flag:

```
ionic cordova run android --device --prod
```

When application is launched, it is stucked on splash screen and using chrome inspector I am seeing this error:

```
ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[function(){}]:
```

Using regular build or build `--release` the app launches as expected.
What is the meaning of this error?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I believe you might have an error in your code. Try running ionic cordova run android --consolelogs --verbose

Comment: This is not an issue of ionic. In your code, you are using a service that should be defined in the module provider.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will try your suggestions. How come it only breaks with --prod flag?

Comment: Prod does a lot of tree shaking and other stuff which does catch more code issues, which is strange i agree;)

Comment: If using @ionic-native/dep@4.x then downgrade them to @ionic-native/dep@3.x that helped me once while building it for --prod